# syntax error, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in Search Plus Custom Mapping

Tags: plugin-development, search, plugin-searchplus

I’m looking for a little help with Custom Mapping for the Search Plus plugin. I think(?) I'm getting pretty close, but stuck on something (and I do front end web design, so this is just over my head) I’m using https://transition.topshelfcraft.com/software/craft/searchplus/usage/hooks-events as a reference and used https://pluginfactory.io to create the plugin.

Per the instructions in the documentation above, I’ve added this to the bottom of the plugin :

```
public function searchPlus_addAlgoliaMapping()
{
    $ret = [];
    $ret['name'] = 'GHCC Staff Mapping2';
    $ret['handle'] = 'GHCC_Staff2';
    $ret['description'] = 'Mapping for Staff Page';
    $ret['method'] = 'example.testMapping';
    return $ret;
}

public function testMapping(element)
{
    $ret = [];

    $ret['objectID'] = $entry->id;
    $ret['title'] = $entry->title;
    $ret['activityId'] = $entry->id;
    $ret['id'] = $entry->id;
    $ret['slug'] = $entry->slug;
    $ret['url'] = $entry->url;
    $ret['uri'] = '/' . $entry->uri;

return $ret;
}
```

But am getting an error: `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)` referencing line 186  `public function testMapping(element)`

Was wondering if anyone had any tips

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Craft but with normal PHP. However.. variables in PHP needs to start with an `$` so `public function testMapping($entry)` will help

Comment: Hey Robin - sorry don't mean to be posting in the wrong place. Do you have a recommendation of where I should post. This is a Craft plugin...

Comment: At the normal https://stackoverflow.com  but since I already answered the question I don't think you'll need that. Maybe you should read common php guides before you start to work with a CMS

Comment: There is a plugin-development tag and a tag for the this particular plugin - I guess I'm not clear on how this doesn't relate to Craft..and appreciate your advice. I've been working on Craft since in beta and haven't had any problems - rarely have to know or use PHP and there is typically a really helpful community

Comment: Voting to leave open. @RobinSchambach just because the _answer_ is a simple PHP error doesn't mean that the _question_ is off-topic. This question is very clearly about a Craft plugin, and therefore definitely belongs here.

Comment: @LindseyD Alright, I'll remember this, sry to bother you again.

Comment: @RobinSchambach No problem. Glad to see you so active on SE, that's a good thing! :)

Comment: Is it possible to provide full documentation on this process please? I have attempted to follow this but when using the "Mapping Test" the RAW Json Output only outputs "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a typo in the [plugin's documentation](https://transition.topshelfcraft.com/software/craft/searchplus/usage/hooks-events).

```
public function testMapping(element)
```

should be

```
public function testMapping($element)
```

since `$element` is a PHP variable.